# Coordinate Transformation, vectors, tensors etc.

Tags: differential-geometry, field-theory, book-recommendation, tensors, online-resources

This is a resource recommendation question. I have started to read classical field theory, although I find it easy, some mathematics in it, I haven't encountered before. These are coordinate transformations, how vector fields change under such a transformation, jacobian of transformation and its purpose, etc. The problem is that I do not know under what broad subject these come under and hence I am not able to find books that encompass it all. I tried reading a book on differential geometry but it took certain topics that I am not aware of for granted. please help.

Comment: to get a suitable recommendation, you should include what prerequisites you're already familiar with, for examplr how much multivariable calculus/topology you know (preferably include the name of any books you used etc) also, differential geometry is a vast subject, so to get better recommendations, you should be more specific. are you trying to learn only the mathematics, or do you want to simultaneously address the classical field theory? basically include what you know, and be specific about the level at which you wish to read the resource (i. e how rigorous/intuitive you want it to be)

Comment: My knowledge in multivariable calculus is from these sources: calculus by Thomas and Finney, advanced engineering mathematics by Erwin kreyszig, essential mathematical methods by Arfken. My main focus is to address classical field theory but i want a solid grip on the mathematics behind it. while reading other topics in physics such as Electromagnetism, Quantum Mech, Special Relativity the mathematics seemed trivial. However, when I started to read classical field theory, I feel my understanding of the mathematics involved is limited. I am confused about where to start.